# An Efficient data structure for Sorted List

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, sortedlist

I want to save my objects according to a key in the attributes of my object in a sorted fashion. Later on I'll access these objects sequentially from max key to min key. I'll do some search tasks as well.

I consider to use either AVL tree or RB Tree. As far as i know they are nearly equivalent in theory(Both have O(logn)). But in practice which one might be better in performance in my situation. And is there a better alternative than those, considering that I'll mostly do insert and sequentially access to the ds.

Edit: I'm going to use java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what it's worth, in C#, `SortedDictionary<K, V>` is implemented as a red-black tree, and in many implementations of the STL in C++, `std::map<K, T>` is implemented as a red-black tree.

Also, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) on AVL vs. red-black trees:

> The AVL tree is another structure
>   supporting O(log n) search, insertion,
>   and removal. It is more rigidly
>   balanced than red-black trees, leading
>   to slower insertion and removal but
>   faster retrieval. This makes it
>   attractive for data structures that
>   may be built once and loaded without
>   reconstruction, such as language
>   dictionaries (or program dictionaries,
>   such as the order codes of an
>   assembler or interpreter).

Comment: I'm using java but the information you provided is useful. Thanx

Comment: To be complete, in C++, `map`, `set`, `multimap` and `multiset` are all implemented in term of Red Black trees in gcc and dinkumware (Visual Studio), though it is no requirement from the standard (only complexity is precised).

Comment: Java's TreeMap also implements Red Black Trees. The interface is called NavigableMap.

Answer (score 1):

Which ever is easiest for you to implement, you won't get better insertion than log(n) with a sorted list and we'd probably need a lot more detail than what you've provided to decide if there are other factors that make another structure more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

As you're doing it in Java, consider using a [TreeSet](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) (although it's a Set, so you can't have duplicate entries)...